# How to add more than one visualizer in a single activity with same audio session id

Tags: android, android-studio

i have added a circular visualizer with a audio session id in my app and it works perfect. when i am trying to add another linear visualizer with the same audio session id below the circular visualizer i get error as:
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: setCaptureSize() called in wrong state: 2

Is it possible to use two audio visualizer with same audio session id at a time?